# getting string of a variable as an output

Tags: python, if-statement

how can I get my output to be the string of a name variable, if the input is equal to the name variable, I want the string of the variable to print. Thanks in advance.

```
    a = 'My name'
    b = 2
    c = 3
    print('input any alphabet of your choice below:')
    print('Enter your name below')
    print('input below')
    running = True
    while running:
      if user_input == a:
         print('This is:', a)
         running = False
      else:
         print('wrong input')
```

Comment: `input()` always returns a string. There's no need to call `str()` on it. Also, please actually copy-paste your code into the textbox here instead of taking a picture, so _we_ can copy-paste your code out to experiment with it and help figure out your issue.

Comment: instead of posting picture of the code, please post the code .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), and [do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also, do not tag your question with `pycharm` unless you think that the problem has to do with *using the Pycharm program*. We don't normally care how you edit your code; the resulting code is the same regardless.

Comment: Also your code appears to work as intended if you input the literal text "My name"

Comment: Anyway: `input` returns **a string**, **not** an integer - ever. I don't think I understand what you mean by "the string of a variable". Are you saying for example that if the user types `a`, then `My name` should be output? And if the user types `b`, then `2` should be output?

Comment: I'm sorry for snapping the code, I'm new here.  I'd  type the code in the textbox next time. Exactly my point sir, @KarlKnechtel . Please,  how can I print My name

Comment: I suspect @KarlKnechtel has correctly read between the lines.  That's not how Python works.  What you want is a dictionary:  `names = { 'a': 'My name', 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }`.  Now you can ask `if user_input in names:` and you can `print(names[user_input])`.

Comment: You can (and should) edit the post to put the code in instead. Click the word "Edit" underneath your post (it is a link).

Comment: Isn't it significantly more work to snap a literal picture of your screen, upload it, and link it, rather than just simply copy/pasting the code here...??? Please see [ask] and [this relevant Meta thread](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: @esqew I will guess: OP may have smartphone with free internet and notebook without internet :) I saw something like this on Facebook: someone had smartphone with free access only to Facebook, and it had to pay for access to rest of internet - so it was sending to Facebook photos of notebook or screenshots from Pyton on smartphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary instead of named variables, so that you can use the input as a key in the dictionary:

```
my_vars = {
    'a': 'My name',
    'b': 2,
    'c': 3,
}

while True:
    try:
        print(f"This is: {my_vars[input()]}")
        break
    except KeyError:
        print('wrong input')
```

```
x
wrong input
b
This is: 2
```